# Difference between Android KeyEvent and keycode

Tags: android, keyevent, keycode

What is the difference?
public boolean onKeyDown (int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
The parameters are keyCode,the button,the user pressed,but what is that KeyEvent?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.Callback.html#onKeyDown%28int,%20android.view.KeyEvent%29

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

> Object used to report key and button events.
>   Each key press is described by a sequence of key events. A key press starts with a key event with ACTION_DOWN. If the key is held sufficiently long that it repeats, then the initial down is followed additional key events with ACTION_DOWN and a non-zero value for getRepeatCount(). The last key event is a ACTION_UP for the key up. If the key press is canceled, the key up event will have the FLAG_CANCELED flag set.

Answer (score 6):

[**KeyEvent**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html): Each key press is described by a sequence of key events, Key events are generally accompanied by a key code.

**`KeyCode`**: is a constant that define the event, and is defined inside `KeyEvent` Class.

For example if you want to detect the KeyEvent "ENTER" :

```
 @Override
  public boolean onKeyDown( int keyCode, KeyEvent event ) {
    if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
      //Do something...
      return true; 
    }
    return super.onKeyDown( keyCode, event );
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

KeyEvent can be used to specify the detailed action, for example:

- ***ACTION_DOWN*** the key has been pressed down but not released
- ***ACTION_UP*** the key has just been released

Usage:

```
keyEvent.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
```